# How to select exploded column value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, exploded

I know, this could easly be done using PHP, but just curious,

How could I explode on `mail` field to select the value from `alias` column with the first exploded part by `@`?

Current:

```
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
| alias | mail                                    |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
|       | user.one@gmail.com                      |
|       | user.two.foo@gmail.com                  |
+-------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Desired:

```
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
| alias        | mail                                    |
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
| user.one     | user.one@gmail.com                      |
| user.two.foo | user.two.foo@gmail.com                  |
+-------+------------------------------------------------+
```

In pseudo code would be like

```
update tablename set tablename.alias = explode('@', tablename.mail)[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
update t
    set alias = substring_index(t.mail, '@', 1);
```